# Rewriting the url in mvc4 which is generating dynamically

Tags: c#, .htaccess, asp.net-mvc-4

My scenario is to rewrite the url which is dynamically generating based on the users login.For example my url is  " mywebsite.com/controllername/methodname?id1=venkatesh%2Fevents" ,I want to change this url into "mywebsite.com/venkatesh/events. I have  tried several scenario's but i didn't find proper solution. I tried the below code but it is not giving proper answer please suggest.

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{

    [RouteArea("area")]
    [RoutePrefix("event",Precedence=1)]
    [RoutePrefix("student", Precedence = 2)]
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/
        [GET("venkatesh")]
      [GET("venkatesh-event",IgnoreAreaUrl=true)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.info = "This is index method";
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Default1/Details/5
        [GET("event{id}")]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.info = "This is details method"+id;
            return View();
        }
```